# Stacking views ... code review needed

Tags: objective-c, uiview

The problem:

1. On top of existing UIView, load a background image
2. From the card deck image (big image), cut 1 card (a part of a big image) and
3. Place that card on top of the background image

The following code works. It does exactly what i need it do to. I ask you though ..

1. Am i doing it right? Is this the way it's done?
2. Are all steps i used really needed? I have a strong suspicion i made it more complicated then it needs to be

Thank you for your time

```
// Define overall UIView area and create a view
UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

// Gain access to background image
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_background.jpg"]; 

// Put background image on top of a 
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];

// So now we have the view of some size with some image bahind it
[background addSubview:myImageView];    


// #####################################################################

CGRect positionOnParentView = CGRectMake(40, 40, 50, 130);

CGImageRef bigImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cards.png"].CGImage;    
CGImageRef partOfABigImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(bigImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50));

// get an image to be displayed
UIImage *partOfImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:partOfABigImage];

// Put it on it's onw view
UIImageView *cardImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:partOfImage];

// create a UIview and add image 
UIView *card = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:positionOnParentView];
[card addSubview:cardImage];

[background addSubview:card];

[[self view] addSubview:background];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating this view hierarchy:

```
UIView (self.view)
  UIView (background)
    UIImageView (backgroundImage - backgroundImage)
    UIView (card)
      UIImageView (cardImage - partOfABigImage)
```

A `UIImageView` can have subviews.  So do you need all of those intermediate views?  Would this simpler hierarchy be sufficient?

```
UIImageView (self.view - backgroundImage)
  UIImageView (cardImage - partOfABigImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Maybe you just didn't include your release statements, but make sure you are releasing the items you call `alloc` on. You can also autorelease them. For example,

   UIView *background = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)] autorelease];
2. Yes, you are doing it right, the only way you will really reduce the amount of code you have here is to give each card it's own image so that you don't have to crop within the big image.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Auto-Reference-Counting (ARC) so you wont need the release stuff ;)